# JPA key value assignment during insertion

Tags: jpa, persistence, cascade, one-to-one

I have 2 tables to join on a OneToOne relationships on their primary key fields.

One of the tables, Owner, has autogeneration  on its primary key field. 
The other table (T2) doesn't.

I'm looking to use JPA to get the PK field value from the Owner table instance it is on and assign that value to the PK field of T2. so that, when I persist the instance of Owner, so shall be the T2 instance.

How is this done?

I tried just about anything that inspires the mind.

The owner class:

```
public class Owner implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;
    Banames t2inst; 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {    return id;    }

    @OneToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public T2 getT2() {    return t2inst;  }

    //...

}
```

The inverse class:

```
public class T2 implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Integer id;  // some other fields here

    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    public Integer getId() {    return id;    }

    // ...

}
```

The insertion code:

```
Owner owner  = new Owner();
T2 t2  = new T2();

owner.setT2(t2);
// t2.setId(owner.getId());

em.persist(owner);
em.getTransaction().commit();
```

The error message:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'id' cannot be null
Error Code: 1048
Call: INSERT INTO T2 (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?)
bind => [2 parameters bound]
Query: InsertObjectQuery(hibernate.T2[ id=null ])
```

Bi-directional relationship (also from T2 to owner), and using @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn didn't work either.

Comment: you have to persist the owner, then get its id and then persist t2, because IDs are generated when the entity is being persisted. PS: indent your code, because it;s really difficult to read

Comment: how can I get that id directly after persisting Owner? the only way I can think of is looking up the last inserted key by using pure SQL. but then, that's no help from jpa.

Comment: persist(owner) -> flush() {not sure if required} -> getOwnerId() -> persist(t2)

Comment: Actually why do you need its Id ? can't you do it like `t2.setOwner(owner)` in this way you wont need the id